# Access 2010 Format Current Date In Report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am using Mircosoft Access 2010 VBA to create a report.  I am trying to use the current date and format it "mmmm dd, yyyyy".

I have a text box with the control source `="As of " & Format(Date(),"mmmm d"", ""yyyy")` and format of `Medium Date`.

It works in Windows 2007 and it shows as "As of April 10, 2018".  BUT if I run it in Windows 10 I get `#Name?`

Does Windows 10 do things differently then Windows 7? Am I missing something that I need to download (I.E. A library file?)

Comment: My guess: your win10 has other locale settings for the separators. You're using comma's here, but perhaps you need something else like semicolons `;`. Furthermore, you don't need the extra quotation marks in your formatting: "mmmm d, yyyy" will work as well and is easier to read.

Comment: Check that the file will compile on Windows 10. If a reference is marked as MISSING you may see errors like this.

Comment: @Calaris When I remove the quotation's it automatically put's them back in.

Comment: @Gustav Thanks, re-compiling on the Windows 10 machine gave me an excel 1.7 error. Re-checking the references helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-compiled on a Windows 10 machine and received a missing or broken reference error for EXCEL.EXE version 1.7.  I re-checked the excel references (Tool > References) and that fixed the issue.